# Remote connect to OS X from Windows - is there dual monitor support?

Tags: windows-7, macos, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have a computer running Windows 7 with two monitors connected to it. I would like to remote connect to a Mac Mini and use both monitors.

Is this possible, or am I stuck with the KVM solution?

Answer (score 1):

A VNC server is included in your Mac OS X system. Here you can find [further instructions](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2010/08/13/setting-up-the-vnc-server-in-mac-os-x-10-6/).

[image]

You will then be able to connect using a VNC client on Windows such as [ultra VNC](http://www.uvnc.com/)

Comment: Care to summarize those instructions here? If the link goes down, your answer will become worthless

Comment: System preferences> Sharing> check the screen sharing combo :p

Comment: Again, I added a screenshot for you. I don't think this answers the question though, the person asking wants *dual monitor* support.

Comment: You understand that you probably won't get many upvotes if you don't include such information in your answer? I recommend you follow @slhck's advice and [read the How to Answer page](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer)!

Comment: @slhck's , @ Ivo Flipse, i'll keep that in mind. concerning the dual monitor issue, considering the client will give you a window you just have to stretch it on your second display to gain dual monitor support. if he wants full os integration it should also work with most vnc clients

Comment: VNC is not an option. It's way to slow and stretching the window is not what I'm looking for, especially not when the monitors have different size and resolution. I was hoping there was a RDP solution with dual monitor support where you can't tell that you are sitting on a remote connection.